# Codeigniter Submit Form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a problem with my submit form.

**This is my controller [offering_member] :**

```
function offering_member {
$idTransaksi = $this->uri->segment(3); //$idTransaksi = 1
$data['anotheruser'] = $this->m_transaksi->getDataUserOffer($idTransaksi)->result(); //parameter $idTransaksi

$this->template_user->display('user/offeringbook/view_offeringbyuser', $data);
}
```

**This is my model [getDataUserOffer] :**

```
function getDataUserOffer($idTransaksi){ //$idTransaksi = 1
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tr_offer');
    $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(tgl_gabung, '%b %d, %Y') AS tgl_gabung", FALSE);
    $this->db->where('tr_offer.id_transaksi', $idTransaksi);
    $this->db->join('user', 'user.id_user = tr_offer.id_user');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query;
}
```

**tr_offer table :**

`id_offer | id_transaksi | id_user | tgl_offer`

```
    1    |      1      |     7     |   2014-09-25
    3    |      1      |     1     |   2014-09-28
```

**And this is my view [view_offeringbyuser.php] :**

```
 <?php $no=0; foreach($anotheruser as $row): $no++;?>
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url('user/offermethod/'.$row->id_transaksi .'/'. $row->id_offer); ?>" method="post" />                
                <div>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url ('assets/img/user/'.$row->foto); ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="<?php echo'#myModal'.$row->id_offer; ?>" alt="..." width="100" height="120">
                </div>          
                <div>
                    <a href='<?php echo site_url('user/member/'.$row->username.'/');?>'><?php echo $row->username; ?></a>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<?php echo 'idOffer'.$no; ?>" value="<?php echo $row->id_offer; ?>">
                </div>
                <center>
                    <input name="hhh" value="<?php echo 'submit'. $no; ?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> </button>
                </center>
            </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This view will display :

```
>    Photo[1] | Photo[2] ---> image
> 
>      ddd[1] | eee[2] ---> username
>
>         1   |    3  ---> input text value id_offer
> 
> Submit1 [1] | Submit2 [2] ---> submit button form
```

When I click Submit1, action will direct to http://*domain*/user/offermethod/1/1

But when I click Submit2, also direct to http://*domain*/user/offermethod/1/**1** << this is should be **3**

I think the problem was in the submit form looping. Input text display true value. But why the **action** form just set **$row->id_offer = 1**, event you click Submit2 button

**I'm sorry for my bad english, Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the form

```
 <?php $no=0; foreach($anotheruser as $row): $no++;?>
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url('user/offermethod/'.$row->id_transaksi .'/'. $row->id_offer); ?>" method="post" />                
                <div>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url ('assets/img/user/'.$row->foto); ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="<?php echo'#myModal'.$row->id_offer; ?>" alt="..." width="100" height="120">
                </div>          
                <div>
                    <a href='<?php echo site_url('user/member/'.$row->username.'/');?>'><?php echo $row->username; ?></a>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<?php echo 'idOffer'.$no; ?>" value="<?php echo $row->id_offer; ?>">
                </div>
                <center>
                    <input name="hhh" value="<?php echo 'submit'. $no; ?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> </button>
                </center>
            </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?> /* Close the form here */
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Oh my. I've been looking for it for 1 hour. And the answer just need 1 line. Thank you so much senk. How to give you some reputation?